# gs can't find the proper font

Tags: fonts, pdf, ghostscript

I am running the following command to add bookmarks to a pdf file. The file `bookmarks.txt` contains bookmarks in Chinese characters and in pdfmarks format. The output of `gs` shows that there seem to be some problem with the font. Is there some way to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
$ gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf note.pdf  bookmarks.txt
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 102.
Page 1
Substituting font Times-Bold for Times New Roman,Bold.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Medi font from /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021004l.pfb... 2889932 1499918 3254752 1759198 3 done.
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb... 2993796 1627069 4166144 2692107 3 done.
Page 2
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Page 3
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Page 4
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Querying operating system for font files...
Loading Arial-BoldMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf... 3073992 1671962 5497244 3026723 3 done.
Loading ArialMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf... 3074368 1692578 5853472 3515223 3 done.
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Page 5
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Page 6
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Page 7
Page 8
Loading Arial-BoldMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf... 3074180 1679830 4371296 2897061 3 done.
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Page 9
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.
Substituting font Times-Bold for Times New Roman,Bold.
Loading Arial-BoldMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf... 3073992 1671819 4631712 2938526 3 done.
Loading ArialMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf... 3073992 1672099 4987940 3383317 3 done.
Page 10
Loading ArialMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf... 3094652 1711038 3749692 2384326 3 done.
```

The font map files of my GhostScript is under `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Init`, and can be viewed here
[Fontmap](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/Fontmap) and 
[Fontmap.GS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/Fontmap.GS).

I have installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, and

```
$ ls /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
Andale_Mono.ttf              Georgia.ttf
andalemo.ttf                 georgiaz.ttf
arialbd.ttf                  impact.ttf
arialbi.ttf                  Impact.ttf
Arial_Black.ttf              timesbd.ttf
Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf        timesbi.ttf
Arial_Bold.ttf               timesi.ttf
Arial_Italic.ttf             Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf
ariali.ttf                   Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf
arial.ttf                    Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf
Arial.ttf                    Times_New_Roman.ttf
ariblk.ttf                   times.ttf
comicbd.ttf                  trebucbd.ttf
Comic_Sans_MS_Bold.ttf       trebucbi.ttf
Comic_Sans_MS.ttf            Trebuchet_MS_Bold_Italic.ttf
comic.ttf                    Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
courbd.ttf                   Trebuchet_MS_Italic.ttf
courbi.ttf                   Trebuchet_MS.ttf
Courier_New_Bold_Italic.ttf  trebucit.ttf
Courier_New_Bold.ttf         trebuc.ttf
Courier_New_Italic.ttf       Verdana_Bold_Italic.ttf
Courier_New.ttf              Verdana_Bold.ttf
couri.ttf                    verdanab.ttf
cour.ttf                     Verdana_Italic.ttf
Georgia_Bold_Italic.ttf      verdanai.ttf
Georgia_Bold.ttf             verdana.ttf
georgiab.ttf                 Verdana.ttf
Georgia_Italic.ttf           verdanaz.ttf
georgiai.ttf                 webdings.ttf
georgia.ttf                  Webdings.ttf
```

---

updated

The error is that in [the generated pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/out.pdf), the bookmarks are not Chinese characters but unrecognizable (if you view it in evince, click side pane and then index). I suspect the substitution is the reason (or do I misunderstand the cause of the problem?)

Here is the updated [Fontmap.GS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/Fontmap.GS), after adding the font files for the four types of Times New Roman fonts

Here is [the output of running the above command using `gs`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/output_gs.txt)

Comment: Do you have these fonts installed? Are `Times New Roman` and `Times New Roman,Bold` available on the system?

Comment: @eppesuig How can I check if I have them installed? thanks.

Comment: `gs` open a file called fontmap. This is normally present in your gs library directory (search it with `find`). This file contains complete font names and their definition file. Some information on how to add fonts to `gs` is available at http://linux.about.com/library/howto/font/blfont5.htm

Comment: @eppesuig: please see my edit to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the right font information. Your `Fontmap.GS` file state that `/TimesNewRoman` is an alias for `/TimesNewRomanPSMT`. But the latter is not available in the same file. Since you have the ttf files in a directory, you only need to update the `fontmap.GS` adding these lines:

```
/TimesNewRomanPSMT (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf) ;
```

You may use the same line as template for the bold font.

Comment: my file is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf

Comment: I add the two to fontmap.GS. `gs` still says `Substituting font Times-Bold for Times New Roman,Bold.
...
Substituting font Times-Roman for Times New Roman.`

Comment: I read once again all your output, and now I think that there is no error there: the font substitution are required by your Fontmap.GS file, and the Arial fonts, once it is not found internally by `gs`, it is found querying the operating system. So, just to be sure: could you please better explain what the error is supposed to be?

Comment: The error is that in [the generated pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/out.pdf), the bookmarks are not Chinese characters but unrecognizable (if you view it in evince, click side pane and then index). I suspect the substitution is the reason (or do I misunderstand the cause of the problem?) Here is the updated [Fontmap.GS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/Fontmap.GS). Here is [the output of `gs`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/fonts/output_gs.txt)